# Minimum value of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find the minimum value of the expression $$y=\frac{16-8\sin^{2} 2x +8\cos^{4} x}{\sin^{2} 2x} .$$ When I convert the expression completely into $2x$, cross multiply and make the discriminant of the quadratic equation greater than $0$, I get the minimum value $-\infty$. I know it is wrong, but why?

Comment: This term is equivalent to $6\cot^{2} x + 4  \tan^{2} x$ , hoping no quick error. Done it in a hurry. Where min is 10

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you simplify?

Comment: I differentiated to get the answer as 9.798

Comment: The middle term doesn't matter. Since $\sin^2 2x=4\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$ we need to minimize $(4+2t^2)/(t(1-t)$ where $t=\cos^2 x$. Routine calculation..

Answer (score 5):

$$y=\frac{16-8\sin^{2} 2x +8\cos^{4} x}{\sin^{2} 2x}$$

or $$y=\frac{16}{4}*\sec^2 x \csc^2 x-8 +\frac{8}{4}\frac{\cos^{4} x}{\sin^2 x* \cos^2 x}$$

or

$$y=4(\tan^2 x +1)(\cot^2 x +1)-8+2 \cot^2 x$$

$$y=4(\tan^2 x + \cot^2 x + 2)-8+2 \cot^2 x$$

Which after simplifying gives,

$$y=4\tan^2 x + 6\cot^2 x$$

Edit: as user suggested the answer in comment is not valid. But one here can easily use AM-GM inequality to reach at correct answer

Comment: Minimum of course at $x=\pi/4$

Comment: @ Mann : No, it is not so. See my answer done with Maple.

Comment: Or well maybe close to it xD

Answer (score 5):

$$8\cos^4x = 8\left(\dfrac{1+\cos (2x)}{2}\right)^2 = 8\left(\dfrac{1+2\cos (2x)+ \cos^2(2x)}{4}\right)=2+4\cos (2x)+2\cos^2(2x) = 2+4t+2t^2, t = \cos (2x) \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{16-8(1-t^2)+2+4t+2t^2}{1-t^2} = \dfrac{10+10t^2+4t}{1-t^2}=f(t), -1 \leq t \leq 1$$. Can you take it from here?